# Really slow evaluation of a simple? list expression

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation, list-manipulation

I believe this is a standard problem, but I could not find a solution anywhere. Possibly because I don't know what to look for. I define a subset of some numbers and I want to count how many are less or equal to $x$. (Is there a better way to do this?)

```
table=Table[N[n^2+m^2],{n,1,3000},{m,1,3000}];
sortedlist=Sort[Apply[Join,Array[table[[#]]&,50]]];
counter[x_]:=Length[Select[sortedlist,#<=x&]];
```

When I plot the function `counter[x]` it works but it takes really long. I assume this is because some part of my definition makes Mathematica evaluate the whole expression over and over again without need. I am really new to Mathematica and I assume that this problem probably has a neat solution already which I just could not find anywhere. Thank you for any advice!

Comment: "When I plot the function counter[x] it works but it takes really long. " How do you plot `counter[x]`? `Plot[counter[x], {x, 0, 9 10^6}]` takes only 6.28 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: Your definition for `sortedlist` could simply be `sortedlist=Sort@Catenate@table[[;;50]]` i think. As for `counter`: You could probably try `LengthWhile[sortedlist,#<=x&]` to exploit the fact that you know the list is sorted.

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? Why the `50` in `Array[table[[#]] &, 50]`?

Answer (score 4):

A zero-order interpolation is a good way to in effect invert the function from positive integers to values in `sortedlist`.

```
Timing[
 table = Table[N[n^2 + m^2], {n, 1, 3000},
  {m, 1, 3000}];
 sortedlist = Sort[Apply[Join,
  table[[1 ;; 50]]]];
 lastpairs = 
  SplitBy[Join[{{0, 0}}, 
     Transpose[{sortedlist,
       Range[Length[sortedlist]]}]], 
     First][[All, -1]];
 ii = Interpolation[lastpairs,
  InterpolationOrder -> 0];]

(* Out[455]= {2., Null} *)
```

It can be plotted like so.

```
Plot[ii[t], {t, 1, Last[sortedlist]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions for simpler methods to find the counts, and to make a plot.

Instead of `Array[table[[#]]&, 50]]` use `table[[;; 50]]`. Check the documentation for [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).

An easy way to count the number of values that are less or equal to $x$, is to count the values with [`Tally`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html), and then total the tallies with [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html).

```
table = Table[N[n^2 + m^2], {n, 1, 3000}, {m, 1, 3000}];

counts = Sort[Tally[Flatten[table[[;; 50]]]]];
counts[[All, 2]] = Accumulate[counts[[All, 2]]];
counts
```

It's easy to graph the counts of values less than or equal to $x$ with [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html).

```
Histogram[Flatten[table[[;; 50]]], Automatic, "CumulativeCount"]
```

[image: cumulative histogram]